# C# property value is by reference for some and by value for others

Tags: c#

I am not sure where is the problem with the code below where value of one class instance change the value of another.  It seems that I have problem  property of type class where the value set in one class affects the value of another class of the same type.  Example is below.  What I want to achieve is after the assignment of value from one class (Result 2) , the subsequent manipulation of the the other class does not effect the previous one.

```cs
public class Address {
    public string Street {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class Person {
    public string Name { 
        get; 
        set; 
    }

    public List<Address> Addresses { 
        get; 
        set; 
    } = new List<Address>();

    public int Age { 
        get; 
        set; 
    }
}

public class Employee {
    public string EmpID {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Person EmployeePerson {
        get;
        set; 
    }
}

var emp = new Employee { 
    EmpID = "1", 
    EmployeePerson = new Person { 
        Name = "Alice", Addresses = 
        new List<Address> { 
            new Address { 
                Street = "123 Street" 
            }
        } 
    } 
};

var per = new Person { 
    Name = emp.EmployeePerson.Name, Addresses = emp.EmployeePerson.Addresses };

per.Addresses[0].Street = "New Street";
per.Name = "New Name";   

Console.WriteLine("Result 1: {0} , {1}", 
    emp.EmployeePerson.Name, per.Name);
    
Console.WriteLine("Result 2: {0} , {1}", 
    emp.EmployeePerson.Addresses[0].Street, per.Addresses[0].Street);
```

**Result 1:** Alice , New Name

**Result 2:** New Street , New Street

Comment: `Result 1: Alice , New Name
Result 2: New Street , New Street` What _exact_ output did you expect?

Comment: The link you have provide seems to be best way to resolve the issue without adding new custom codes.

Answer (score 3):

`List<T>` is a reference type. In your example, `emp.EmployeePerson` and `per` have both a reference to the same list. If you manipulate the list, you will see the changes in both variables.

You can avoid this by creating a new list when you initialise the `per` variable by copying the old list. But `Address` is also a reference types, so both lists will hold references to the same instance. You also have to copy your address variables. I added a `Copy()` method to your `Address` class:

```
var per = new Person { Name = emp.EmployeePerson.Name, Addresses = emp.EmployeePerson.Addresses.Select<Address,Address>(x => x.Copy()).ToList() };

public class Address
{
    public string Street {get;set;}
        
    public Address Copy()
    {
        return new Address { Street = this.Street };
    }
}
```

The distinction between reference types and value types is quite fundamental in C#. Here is some information from the official documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types
https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types

Comment: How do I assign the Addresses without transforming it to a List<string>

Comment: I am sorry, I thought Address is a list of strings. Because it is a list of your `Address` class, it makes it a bit more complicated. You'll have to copy the list and the instances of your `Address` class

Comment: Make addresses readonly like so: `public List<Address> Addresses { get; } = new List<Address>();` (i.e. remove the setter). Then do not assign to addresses, but add new addresses: `Addresses.Add(new Address {...})`.

Comment: Is there a better way around this?.  I mean to convert the reference type to value type.

Comment: `List<T>` is always a reference type. If you want `Address` also being a value type, change it from `class` to `struct`. But before you go on, I recommend you to do a lot of reading, because if you don't understand how to deal with reference and value types, you will be lost quite soon.